# How do I find out if there is an Esperanto club in my city?

Tags: culture

I first found out there was a club in my city through a [JEF](https://www.jef-hamburg.de/), young European federalists event, but it took quite some time - and the help of a friend - until I went there the first time.

How do I find out if there is an Esperanto club in my city?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. google Esperanto + yourcityname (by this way I found an event in my city)
2. search on Facebook for Esperanto + yourcityname
3. ask the Esperanto organization of your country how to contact the local group
4. ask on [Telegram](https://telegramo.org) in one of the language groups or in the main group, be patient
5. ask on Facebook in the biggest Esperanto group (more than 20k people)

Answer (score 4):

I would like to second what Aviadisto said, especially the google search. Esperanto in my own city is very easy to find and comes right up in a google search. I've said before that if people can't find us, they're not really looking.

There isn't really one good way to look -- or even five good ways to look - so look every possible. Picking up where Aviadisto left off:

6. Check meetup.com
7. Contact the Esperanto club of a neighboring city.
8. Search Duolingo for references to your city name.
9. Check out the search tips at "Trovu Samurbanon" on FB (https://www.facebook.com/Trovu-samurbanojn-E-istojn-%C4%89ie-586767024717907/)

Comment: Oh cool, "Trovu samurbanojn!" - tion mi sxatas.